# Почему исчезает label_1 когда я применяю self.setStyleSheet('background:red;')?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Я создал два `label` и решил центрировать их с помощью `QGridLayout` Но почему то когда я применяю
`self.setStyleSheet('background:red;')` то `label_1` исчезает.
Можно ли это как то исправить?

Мне нужно что бы и `self.setStyleSheet('background:red;')` работал и два `labels` было видно
Использовать просто `setGeometry` не подходит так как мне нужно динамическое центрирование.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        
        self.setStyleSheet('background:red;')
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_1.setText("-")
        label_1.setStyleSheet('font-size:100px')
        label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_1, 0,0,1,1)
        
        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_2.setText("|")
        label_2.setStyleSheet('font-size:100px')
        label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_2, 0,0,1,1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: в доках написано 'background-color: red;'

Comment: @Интик напишите пожалуйста подробнее, что написано в доках и как оно влияет на решение данного вопроса?

Comment: @orlatym скажите пожалуйста, почему вы используете два `label`, а не один с текстом `┼` ?

Comment: @S.Nick Я просто взял их для примера. Нет особого значения в количестве объектов и что это будет `QLabel` `QWidget` `QRadio` и так далее. Главное что бы они все были центрированы внутри widget и если не указан размер главного виджета то он растягивался в зависимости от того какая точка является крайней. В данном случае если нет `resize` то высота  `self`= `label_2` а ширина `self` = `label_1`.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Я знаю что один `label` перекрывает другой. но если удалить `self.setStyleSheet('background:red;')` то оба `labels` видно. Почему так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему так, пока не знаю - надо поэкспериментировать, а
добиться желаемого эффекта можно так:

> первой метке грида задать желаемый цвет фона, а последующим меткам
> задавать прозрачный фон

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #...

        label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_1.setText("\\")

        # Желаемый цвет фона
        label_1.setStyleSheet('background-color:red; font-size:100px')
        #...

        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_2.setText("|")

        # прозрачный фон в формате #AARRGGBB, 
        # здесь АА - это степень прозрачности от 0 - прозрачный, до FF - абсолютно не прозрачный
        label_2.setStyleSheet('background:#00000000; font-size:100px')
        #...
```

Comment: Странно когда я пытался использовать `rgba` то у меня ничего не вышло. Но ваш вариант работает.

Answer (score 0):

ваш вопрос как всегда не обычный, но он также имеет решение.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet('background: red;')        
        
        lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.setSpacing(0)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_1.setText("-")
        label_1.setStyleSheet('font-size: 100px;')
        label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_1, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        
        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label_2.setText("|")
        label_2.setFixedWidth(8)
        label_2.setStyleSheet('font-size: 100px;')
        label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(label_2, 0, 1, 3, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это работает только когда `label_1.setText('-')` и `label_2.setText('|')`. Но когда я меняю текст в `label_2` на чтото другое то текст перестает работаь как надо.